# Making ArcGIS Online web app where symbology changes according to user-selected field(s)

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online

I have been asked to develop a web application for territorial development. I have no experience building a web application. As my organization has ArcGIS licences, I was encouraged to first look into ArcGIS Online.

**Background**

The area of interest is divided into 39 districts. For each district, the overall production of some 20 types of resources has been estimated. The end users may be interested in one or several resources as raw material for their activities.

**Requested functionalities**

Users can select one or more resource(s) of interest.
Based on this selection, the symbology (colour gradient) reflects the tonnage of selected resource(s). In case several resources are selected, the tonnage is simply the sum of each resource's tonnage.

Here is roughly the current structure of the data (feature class):

| District name | District code | Resource A (t) | Resource B (t) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| District A | 0001 | 31 | 10 |
| District B | 0002 | 17 | 11 |
| District C | 0003 | 29 | 9 |
| District D | 0004 | 15 | 7 |

I have been looking into ArcGIS Online features in the past few days. But I still have not figured out how to implement the requested functionalities. Filters only seem to apply to field values. And symbology does not seem to be dynamic inside apps.

I can sum up fields with an Arcade expression in Map Viewer, and change the symbology accordingly. However, I do not know how to make the array of fields dynamic, by linking it to some kind of list widget for instance.

The Arcade expressions also seem more tricky to implement inside apps and widgets.

I have spent quite some time on it already and decided it was time to ask for advice.

Shall I change the structure of my data, maybe?

Comment: I focused your question on ArcGIS Online. If you wish to also ask about R and Python then please use separate questions for those and because they will involve coding you would need to include a code attempt to ask them.

Comment: Have you considered adding multiple layers for the same data source, but with different symbology?  Then turn layers on/off, depending on which symbology you want to use?  I think that you might be able to do this in an ArcGIS Online 'Story Map' web app, according to https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-instant-apps-questions/which-ago-applications-allow-users-to-turn-layers/td-p/825148 (but I've not tried this myself).

Comment: @SonofaBeach I did consider it. The main issue is the number of possibilities. There are currently 26 different resources considered in the study. Depending on the activity the user wants to start, some resources (raw materials) can substitute each other. hence the possibility to combine them.
My next sketchy idea was to use transparency. Then all symbology needs to align.

Comment: Thank you for the edit @PolyGeo

Comment: As a follow-up: I reached out to my company's ESRI contact. This functionality does not currently exist in AGOL. However, they seem rather confident it can be developed. They sent me [link to their API reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/), but I think they will have worked out a solution before my schedule allows me to dive into it. Thanks for your contributions!